# Как открыть форму если форма находиться в другой папке

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Форма и код который я пишу находиться в разных  папках
Код(в папке нет той формы который указываю):

```
protected string GetClientsHistoryUrl(string iinbin)
{
    return "javascript:window.open('InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin.ToString() + "','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ')";
}
```

Выводить ошибку нет такой формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено через функцию `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`

```
protected string GetClientsHistoryUrl(string iinbin)
{
    string javaScript = "javascript:window.open('{0}','_blank','status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no')";
    string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Path/to/resource/InsurerHistory.aspx?iinbin=" + iinbin);

    return string.Format(javaScript, path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать это:

```
Response.Redirect("путь к форме");
```